# Can we plot SCATTER PLOT like this In Tableau public...if yes then How?

Tags: tableau-api, public

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56qHd.png)

How can we plot this kind of graph in Tableau Public???

Comment: Plz check the image (nter image description here) above

Comment: The scatter plot is easy: just put the x and y values on the row and column axes. But you might need a dual axis plot to get the line to appear which will require a calculation.